# Number of months between 2 java.util.Date, excluding day of month

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I want the number of months between 2 `java.util.Date`'s, without the days in month counted.
So I just want the year and month in the comparison.

#### Example:

```
 monthsBetween(new Date(2012,01,28), new Date(2012,02,01)) ---> 1

 monthsBetween(new Date(2012,02,27), new Date(2012,02,28)) ---> 0

 monthsBetween(new Date(2012,03,28), new Date(2012,07,01)) ---> 4
```

I have tried this (returns 0, expected 1), using Joda-time:

```
private static int monthsBetween(final Date fromDate, final Date toDate) {
    DateTime date1 = new DateTime().withDate(2012, 1, 20);
    DateTime date2 = new DateTime().withDate(2012, 2, 13);
    PeriodType monthDay = PeriodType.yearDayTime().withDaysRemoved();
    Period difference = new Period(date1, date2, monthDay);
    int months = difference.getMonths();
    
    return months;
 }
```

And also this (same results), using Joda-time:

```
private static int monthsBetween(final Date fromDate, final Date toDate) {
        return Months.monthsBetween(new DateTime(fromDate), new   DateTime(toDate).getMonths();
    }
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What time zone do you want to use to interpret the `Date` values?

Comment: I will use TimeZone="GMT+1", something else I need to think about in that case?

Comment: Always GMT+1? Fair enough if that's what you need - but it does sound a little odd. Basically, you just need to be aware that what date a particular instant in time falls into depends on time zone. (And calendar system, but that's less likely to be an issue.)

Comment: Yes, always GMT+1. Ok thanks for the information!

Comment: You probably noticed that new java.util.Date(int year, int month, int date) is deprecated? Are you aware that year is supposed to be the year minus 1900 and month = the month between 0-11?

Comment: Good point! Yes, I noticed that. And yes, I'm aware of that, that part was just "pseudocode". But I shouldn't write code that is wrong or deprecated of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're asking for the number of whole months - which isn't the same as saying "ignore the day of month part".

To start with, I'd suggest using [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) instead of [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) for the computations. Ideally, don't use `java.util.Date` at all, and take your input as `LocalDate` to start with (e.g. by parsing text straight to that, or wherever your data comes from.) Set the day of month to 1 in both dates, and *then* take the difference in months:

```
private static int monthsBetweenIgnoreDays(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    start = start.withDayOfMonth(1);
    end = end.withDayOfMonth(1);
    return Months.monthsBetween(start, end).getMonths();
}
```

Comment: @BasilBourque: The OP didn't start off with `DateTime` values - they started with `Date` values. Changing those to be `LocalDate` means knowing which time zone to use, etc. It's not at all obvious that the OP really *needed* do start with `Date` objects though...

Answer (score 5):

This version is JDK Calendar based:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date d1 = f.parse("2012-01-01");
    Date d2 = f.parse("2012-02-02");
    int n = differenceInMonths(d1, d2);
    System.out.println(n);
}

private static int differenceInMonths(Date d1, Date d2) {
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c1.setTime(d1);
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    c2.setTime(d2);
    int diff = 0;
    if (c2.after(c1)) {
        while (c2.after(c1)) {
            c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            if (c2.after(c1)) {
                diff++;
            }
        }
    } else if (c2.before(c1)) {
        while (c2.before(c1)) {
            c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
            if (c1.before(c2)) {
                diff--;
            }
        }
    }
    return diff;
}
```

Comment: I noticed these two dates return 0: `2011-01-01 00:00:00 CST --- 2011-02-01 00:00:00 CST`. I think the two if's before `diff++` and `diff--` should include `|| c2.equals(c1)` don't you think?

Comment: Or, maybe the milliseconds are the problem... No, since it returns 1 just adding the "or equals"

Comment: This is a linear algorithm. If the input is 2 very far dates, it can take a bit time. At least consider binary search.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the years and months in an int value:

```
months = (year2-year1)*12 + month2 - month1;
```

Being 12 months in a year.

Comment: Using an api like `Calendar.add()` would be better

Comment: Sorry, but I can't figure out how to solve the problem (count months between two dates) using `Calendar.add()`. Some example, please?

Also I make the assumption _if you have int values_

Also, in my opinion, one simple line of code is better than importing a class you don't need for anything else (this only applies if there's no more Calendar objects in the project).

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:** Since you do not need time and timezone to consider in your requirement, [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/date.html) fits best to your requirement.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(monthsBetween(LocalDate.of(2012, 1, 28), LocalDate.of(2012, 2, 1)));
        System.out.println(monthsBetween(LocalDate.of(2012, 2, 27), LocalDate.of(2012, 2, 28)));
        System.out.println(monthsBetween(LocalDate.of(2012, 3, 28), LocalDate.of(2012, 7, 1)));
    }

    static int monthsBetween(final LocalDate fromDate, final LocalDate toDate) {
        return Math.toIntExact(
                    ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(
                            fromDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()),
                            toDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth())
                    )
                );
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
0
4
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Chuufj)

### In case you need to use `java.util.Date`:

For any reason, if you need to do it for the objects of `java.util.Date`, you can convert the objects of `java.util.Date` to `Instant` using [`Date#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--) which can be converted to other `java.time` types as required.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // Test
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
        
        System.out.println(monthsBetween(sdf.parse("2012-01-28"), sdf.parse("2012-02-01")));
        System.out.println(monthsBetween(sdf.parse("2012-02-27"), sdf.parse("2012-02-28")));
        System.out.println(monthsBetween(sdf.parse("2012-03-28"), sdf.parse("2012-07-01")));
    }

    static int monthsBetween(final Date fromDate, final Date toDate) {
        ZonedDateTime zdtFrom = fromDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        ZonedDateTime zdtTo = toDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        
        return Math.toIntExact(
                    ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(
                            zdtFrom.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()),
                            zdtTo.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth())
                    )
                );
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
0
4
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Dpp4Xg)

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Some important notes:**

1. The constructor, `java.util.Date(int, int, int)` is deprecated.
2. `java.util.Date` and [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int)) month is 0-based i.e. January is month#0. However, `SimpleDateFormat` considers January as month#1.
3. An `int` prefixed with 0 is considered as an octal number which can support digit only in the range of 0-7. You did not encounter a compilation error merely by chance because you have used months only up to 07. Had you used 08 or 09, for example, you would have encountered a compilation error.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Gets number of months between two dates. 
 * <p>Months are calculated as following:</p>
 * <p>After calculating number of months from years and months from two dates,
 * if there are still any extra days, it will be considered as one more month.
 * For ex, Months between 2012-01-01 and 2013-02-06 will be 14 as 
 * Total Months = Months from year difference are 12 + Difference between months in dates is 1  
 * + one month since day 06 in enddate is greater than day 01 in startDate.
 * </p>
 * @param startDate
 * @param endDate
 * @return
 */
public static int getMonthsBetweenDates(Date startDate, Date endDate)
{
    if(startDate.getTime() > endDate.getTime())
    {
        Date temp = startDate;
        startDate = endDate;
        endDate = temp;
    }
    Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    startCalendar.setTime(startDate);
    Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    endCalendar.setTime(endDate);

    int yearDiff = endCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)- startCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int monthsBetween = endCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)-startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) +12*yearDiff;

    if(endCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) >= startCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
        monthsBetween = monthsBetween + 1;
    return monthsBetween;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just get the year and month fields of Calendar instances, convert the years to months and get differences.

```
private static int monthsBetween(final Date s1, final Date s2) {
    final Calendar d1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    d1.setTime(s1);
    final Calendar d2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    d2.setTime(s2);
    int diff = (d2.get(Calendar.YEAR) - d1.get(Calendar.YEAR)) * 12 + d2.get(Calendar.MONTH) - d1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    return diff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work for leap year also

```
public static int getNumberOfMonths(Date fromDate, Date toDate) {
    int monthCount = 0;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(fromDate);
    int c1date = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int c1month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int c1year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    cal.setTime(toDate);
    int c2date = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int c2month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int c2year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    System.out.println(" c1date:"+c1date+" month:"+c1month+" year:"+c1year);
    System.out.println(" c2date:"+c2date+" month:"+c2month+" year:"+c2year);
    GregorianCalendar grCal = new GregorianCalendar();
    boolean isLeapYear1 = grCal.isLeapYear(c1year);
    boolean isLeapYear2 = grCal.isLeapYear(c2year);
    monthCount = ((c2year - c1year) * 12) + (c2month - c1month);
    if(isLeapYear2 && c2month == 1 && c2date == 29){
        monthCount = monthCount+ ((c1date == 28)?0:1);
    }else if(isLeapYear1 && c1month == 1 && c1date == 29){
        monthCount = monthCount+ ((c2date == 28)?0:1);
    }else{
        monthCount = monthCount+ ((c2date >= c1date)?0:1);
    }
    return monthCount;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will fetch you difference in months

```
(endCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)*12+endCal.get(Calendar.MONTH))-(startCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)*12+startCal.get(Calendar.MONTH))
```