# How to get total number of months from a specific Date?

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime

I am new to Android.I have a requirement, I have a field to enter the Date Of Birth of a person.On successful selection I wanna return the total number of months from the DOB to current date.For example, if I entered DOB as 19/10/2012 I wanna return 36(months).I searched for this, but didn't find anything suitable to my requirement.Here is my current code which return sucessful data,

```
private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
    cal.set(year, month, day);
    Date date = cal.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    if(System.currentTimeMillis() > date.getTime()) {
        edtDate.setText(sdf.format(date));
        LocalDate date1 = new LocalDate(date);
        LocalDate date2 = new LocalDate(new java.util.Date());
        PeriodType monthDay = PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime();
        Period difference = new Period(date1, date2, monthDay);
        int months = difference.getMonths();
        months=months + 1;
        System.out.println("16102015:Nunber of Months"+months);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(mActivity,getResources().getString(R.string.date_validationmsg),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

Comment: what is your question actually ?

Comment: @robodev  i wanna get total number of months from a date i selected?

Comment: oke, check my answer pass two dates to the function if you are not interested to use JodaTime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Calendar startCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
startCalendar.setTime(startDate);
Calendar endCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
endCalendar.setTime(endDate);

int diffYear = endCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - startCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int diffMonth = diffYear * 12 + endCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) - startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Comment: how to set current date as endDate using GregorianCalendar

Comment: you can simply use your java date as well

Comment: Thanks it seems getting the output.Voted for your answer.I will verify the answer if it met my requirement

Comment: i want to be  add specific number of months to the DOB and show that exact date  -DAY,MONTH, an YEAR.If i have a date 20/02/2014and i add 3 months i have to show 20 MAY 2014. can you help on this?

Comment: calender.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92724/discussion-between-noufal-m-and-arijit-mukherjee).

Answer (score 3):

To start with, I'd suggest using [LocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) instead of [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) for the computations. Ideally, don't use `java.util.Date` at all, and take your input as LocalDate to start with (e.g. by parsing text straight to that, or wherever your data comes from.) Set the day of month to 1 in both dates, and then take the difference in months:

```
private static int monthsBetweenDates(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    start = start.withDayOfMonth(1);
    end = end.withDayOfMonth(1);
    return Months.monthsBetween(start, end).getMonths();
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566630/number-of-months-between-2-java-util-date-excluding-day-of-month) link the OP is accepted the same answer because `Months.monthsBetween()` method is not working proper for him

**UPDATE 2**

```
LocalDate userEnteredDate = LocalDate.parse( new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date));    
LocaleDate currentDate =  LocalDate.parse( new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()));

int months = monthsBetweenDates(userEnteredDate, currentDate)
```

Comment: Can you suggest the input.Mine is as shown in the above code Date date = cal.getTime(); which is the start date.

Comment: @NoufalM have you checked the answer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92693/discussion-between-robo-dev-and-noufal-m).

Answer (score 1):

Using Joda-time library [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), I was able to get the desired result.
Try the below code it would give the desired the difference in months.

```
    DateTime date1 = new DateTime().withDate(2012, 10, 19);
    DateTime today = new DateTime().withDate(2015, 10, 19);
    // calculate month difference
    int diffMonths = Months.monthsBetween(date1.withDayOfMonth(1), today.withDayOfMonth(1)).getMonths();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JodaTime, it's really easy:

- http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/

  `int nMonths = new Period(startTime, endTime).getMonths();`

Comment: I am getting 0 as the output

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to calculate months between two dates

```
public static int monthsBetweenUsingJoda(Date d1, Date d2) {
    return Months.monthsBetween(new LocalDate(d1.getTime()), new LocalDate(d2.getTime())).getMonths();
}
```